# why the convolution of two functions of moderate decrease is again function of moderate decrease?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I need to prove that a convolution of 2 functions of moderate decrease is a function of moderate decrease.
I tried to split the integral into two integrals but I couldn't manage to bound any one of them by $\frac{A}{x^2+1}$.

Thanks

Comment: What is your precise definition for moderate decrease? There are several (equivalent) definitions, but it will be easier to write an answer using the one you are familiar with instead of a different one.

Comment: definition of moderate decrease function- A function f defing on R is said to be moderate decrease if f is continuous and there exists a constant A>0 so that A/(x^2+1)

Answer (score 5):

Take $z = x - y/2$. 
$$ \begin{align*}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + x^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + (y-x)^2} \mathrm{d}x &= 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1 + (y/2 + z)^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + (y/2 - z)^2} \mathrm{d}z \\ 
& \leq \frac{2}{1 + (y/2)^2} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1 + (y/2 - z)^2} \mathrm{d}z \\
& \leq \frac{2}{1 + (y/2)^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1 + (y/2 - z)^2} \mathrm{d}z \\
& = \frac{2}{1 + (y/2)^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1 + w^2} \mathrm{d}w \end{align*}$$

Lastly observe
$$ \frac{2}{1 + (y/2)^2} \leq \frac{2}{1/4 + (y/2)^2} \leq \frac{8}{1 + y^2} $$

---

The power $2$ in $(1 + x^2)^{-1}$ is not special. For any power $1+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon > 0$ you get a similar result.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+(y/2+z)^2} \leq \frac{1}{1+(y/2)^2}$ only if $y$ is positive. If it's negative, use $\frac{1}{1+(y/2-z)^2} \leq \frac{1}{1+(y/2)^2}$. You can then proceed with the same proof.